# What podcast apps include variable speed playback?

Tags: applications, podcast

I know about [Astro Player](http://www.astroplayer.com/). Any other apps that feature podcast managment and variable speed playback?

Comment: Speeding them up on the computer might be a very easy way to get this, but probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

If you'll pardon the "non-answer"...

I wrote [Taffy](https://github.com/lancehilliard/Taffy) to act as a proxy between your Android device and the podcast provider.  It speeds up the podcast before your podcatcher downloads it.  There are several undesirable aspects to this approach (hosting not the least among them, nor inability to *change* playback speed during playback), but I use it every day to listen to several podcasts on my Droid at faster speeds.

Here's to it becoming obselete soon.

My Droid uses [BeyondPod](http://www.beyondpod.mobi/android/index.htm), pointed to Taffy podcast feeds, to automatically download all of my podcasts straight to my handset during pre-dawn hours.  I wake every morning (and have for months -- Taffy's a pain to setup, but it's pretty smooth sailing from there) to no-hassle, "sped-up" podcasts ready for my commute.

Comment: That sounds awesome. Do you have Taffy hosted anywhere where anyone else could make use of it? I'd think that a site hosting sped up podcast feeds could pay for itself.

Comment: I don't have it hosted anywhere.  You think a hosting company would welcome it?  It's pretty CPU intensive (that could be tuned by the hosting company, I suppose).  Then there's the business of the LAME encoder runtime dependency.  Would that prevent my hosting it somewhere?  These are questions I've never taken the time to answer.  The biggest (darn near the only, IMHO) hassle with Taffy is getting it setup.  It would be really nice if folks could skip that step.

Comment: Looks like taffy has been obsoleted by Presto http://taffy.codeplex.com/discussions/272356

Comment: Correct. I no longer develop Taffy. I've been using Presto quite happily for over a year!

Answer (score 4):

Today, [Presto](http://www.aocate.com/presto/) entered open beta.  Presto provides a background Service which allows other applications to play MP3 and Ogg Vorbis files on your Android device at faster or slower speeds and/or faster or slower pitches, so that any application can have variable speed playback, as long as the end user has Presto installed. Developers must modify their app for Presto to be used while playing audio, and I've released open source code to make that almost a drop-in replacement for the Android MediaPlayer.

BeyondPod, DoggCatcher, and PodTrapper have all been working with me in the course of development, so should have a version that can use Presto

Answer (score 3):

[AntennaPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.danoeh.antennapod) recently included support for variable speed playback via Presto.

Answer (score 1):

Astro Player Beta will go up to 2x I think.  Works pretty well.

Comment: Yes, but as the question mentioned, looking for a player other than Astro. Personally, I find Astro Player to be very lacking.

Answer (score 0):

BeyondPod Podcast Manager ([free trial](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-podcast-manager/mobi.beyondpod), [$6.99 unlock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-unlock-key/mobi.beyondpod.unlockkey)) will play at 1.5 and 2 times speed, however you also need to purchase the [Presto Sound Library Open Beta ($3.99)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/presto-sound-library-open-beta/com.aocate.presto) to enable that particular functionality.

Works well once you've done that, though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doubleTwist? I have been enjoying this music app very much.

Comment: I downloaded doubleTwist and can't find any options for changing the playback speed.

Comment: Oh,  I see,  you want to make it go by faster.

Answer (score -2):

as of today, there is no android application that supports podcast management and variable speed playback.

Comment: Not so. The question links to Astro Player, which includes variable speed playback and podcast management.